# Create multiple paths by joining a set of start points in one layer to a single end destination in another layer?

Tags: qgis, point, line

I need to create a batch of paths so that I can calculate the best potential placement of a development site by counting the number of intersecting features along that path.

I have a grid of points in one layer and a single point in another. I would like to create a line for each of the features in the start layer to the single point in the other layer.

Most of points to line features only take one layer as an input or either take two layers with a single feature.

QGIS on MacOS El Cap

Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: QGIS on MacOS El Cap.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS you can make use of the virtual layers.

Go to `Layer/ Add layer/ add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. Replace `source` and `destination` by the real layer name.

```sql
select a.id, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry)
from source a, destination b
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very helpful - although I get an error saying no column with ID, tried changing it to other column names but no avail

Comment: @ChrisPage yes, you can use any field name from the input layers. In the answer, the field is named `id` and belongs to the `source` layer. Notice I gave an alias `a` and `b` to the layers, and so I can use these aliases in the `select`